# Interpreting user-entered expressions (securely) in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a Rails app which has an e-commerce element for multiple clients - and I'd like those clients to be able to specify, in an admin area, a formula for calculating their shipping amount; for the methods may differ.

Let's pretend for a moment that I allowed them to enter ruby code, and then I later (at the point of calculating the shipping for an order) eval'ed the result - it would be rather flexible, as, if I set-up some appropriate variables beforehand, they could enter differing formulae, such as:

- 5.00 *# A static amount - always charge 5.00*
- order.total * 0.1 *# 10% of the order value*
- [order.total*0.1, 3.00].max *# 10% of the total, or 3.00, whichever is greater*
- order.shipping_abroad? ? 10.00 : 5.00 *# 10.00 for overseas customers, 5.00 for domestic*

... and of course, a hundred variations on those themes.

Now, the problem is that eval'ing their code as ruby would be a security nightmare, permitting them to shell out to the system, access my database, and generally wreak havoc, whether by accident or design. $SAFE doesn't appear to be a guarantee to safety, from my understanding.

So, my actual question (yes, I do have one, eventually!) is: is there a simple, safe scripting language with which I can allow users to enter expressions (using variables that I pre-seed) and later calculate the expressions' results, but which doesn't allow system calls, db access, etc.?

I have to be able to interpret and run the language from within ruby, but the language itself doesn't have to be ruby - it can be pretty much anything, although I'd prefer it to be fairly readable for clients, and be able to cope with the sort of expressions I'm using in the ruby example above. Brownie points if there's the ability for me to syntax-check the expression when they enter it to point out any obvious errors to the client.

(Unless, of course, you can point me in the direction of how to do a "safe", sandboxed eval in ruby, which would meet the requirements as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For entering arbitrary values, I would suggest having a look at something like Liquid Templates or Radiant Tags - you can build your own template language that isolates the interpreted code.

Another approach would be to use JavaScript (or CoffeeScript) and integrate with a JS interpreter - there are a number of tools that connect Ruby to the various JS VMs.

That said, I think it might be easier to just handle this via some smart UI, rather than having users enter equations. Pick a couple of the most likely shipping options, and build a set of widgets for entering the values, which can then simply be verified as integers.

Each one of you examples could actually be handled using this approach

- Always charge: $X
- X% of the order value
- X% of the total, or $Y, whichever is greater

Safe, and might be a more friendly approach from a UX perspective.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. There's some good ideas there; I'm quite drawn by your Javascript suggestion (johnson or therubyracer, perhaps), although one of your templating options may be viable too if they cope with complex enough expressions; I will check them out!

Answer (score 0):

> is there a simple, safe scripting language with which I can allow users to enter expressions

[Lua](http://www.lua.org/) has always been known as such.